# Rails calculate Date duration from start_date and end_date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails 6 app I've got a model with fields:

```
  create_table "events", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.date "start_date", null: false
    t.date "end_date"
    t.integer "duration"
  end
```

When duration is not provided I need to have mechanism which calculates the missing value if `start_date` and `end_date` are given. The solution is pretty simple I guess:

```
  def duration_calculator(start_date, end_date)
    end_date - start_date
  end

2.7.1 :049 > start_date
 => Mon, 15 Feb 2021
2.7.1 :050 > end_date
 => Mon, 15 Feb 2021
2.7.1 :051 > end_date - start_date
 => (0/1)
```

But it won't worked - I was expecting to get 1 since the event lasted all day. How to achieve that behaviour?

Comment: `(end_date - start_date) + 1`?

Comment: "Why does `x - x = 0`, not `1`?"

Comment: Alternatively you could use `(start_date..end_date).count`, i.e. an an inclusive range. But `count` isn't optimized for dates, so it has to traverse the entire range in order to count the days.

Comment: @Stefan the thing is how to handle end result formatting e.g. when `end_date = Date.today + 10` I'll have `=> (11/1)` instead of number 11.

Comment: @mr_muscle you can call `to_i` to convert a rational to an integer. Or you could base your calculation on the date's [`jd`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-jd) value. (which would also optimize the aforementioned `count` call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid the rational number, you could use a inclusive range and count the number of days via:

```
(start_date..end_date).count
```

Unfortunately, `count` actually traverses the range instead of just *calculating* the difference.

You could calculate the difference yourself using [`jd`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-jd) – the [Julian day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day) number:

```
end_date.jd - start_date.jd + 1
```

Or combine both of the above into:

```
(start_date.jd..end_date.jd).count
```

Here, `count` *calculates* the difference, because it is an integer range.

Note that the range-based solutions don't allow negative results because ranges are always ascending in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, `start_date` is equal to `end_date` as both are `Mon, 15 Feb 2021`, so the result in console is correct. The returned fraction can be cast into an integer format by `(end_date - start_date).to_i`, but of course this will still return `0`.

You should use `DateTime` instead of `Date` if you want to be more exact on timing of events, or you could adjust your helper to the following to ensure the smallest duration is 1:

```
 def duration_calculator(start_date, end_date)
    if end_date == start_date
        1
    else
        end_date - start_date
    end
 end
```

Note, you would have to consider here about an event with a `start_date` of today, and an `end_date` of tomorrow, as that would also return `1`.

## EDIT

Updating the method above so the method will return the number of days spanned:

```
def duration_calculator(start_date, end_date)
    duration_in_seconds = end_date.at_end_of_day - start_date.at_beginning_of_day
    duration_in_days = duration_in_seconds/86400 # seconds in one day
    duration_in_days.to_i # round to nearest day
 end
```

Comment: An event starting today and ending tomorrow sounds more like 2 days.

Comment: Depends if youre talking about day spanned or a time elapsed. See question for update if youre just talking about days spanned.